# java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java)

Tags: android, android-camera, runtimeexception, android-mediarecorder

I have integrated camera in my app.When user click on capture button i am making toolbar hide so that camera preview screen size increases.This crashes the app on stopping the recording on line -    `mMediaRecorder.stop();`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
       at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java)
```

However if i don't hide the toolbar or never show the toolbar then there is no crash.So the problem is because the camera params changes after i hide the toolbar.How could i resolve this?I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833694/mediarecorder-stop-stop-failed-1007) answer and added tht code to `CameraPreview` class.

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
mCamera = getCameraInstance();
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
mPreview = new CameraPreview(mActivity, mCamera);
preview = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(mPreview);
capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
mToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
    // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
    // now you can start recording
    mMediaRecorder.start();
}
}
}):

stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
mCamera.lock(); 
}
}):
```

CameraPreview.class

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
//            if(mCamera==null)
//            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth,profile.videoFrameHeight);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        Log.e("surfaceDestroyed issue","surfaceDestroyed called");
        if ((mCamera != null)&&(!CameraActivity.getInstance().getOnBackPressedListener().isPreview())) {
            Log.e("surfaceDestroyed issue","surface destroyed");
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("error", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
```

Error-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
       at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java)
       at xyzCameraFragment$5.onClick(CameraFragment.java:208)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: Post your stack-trace!!

Comment: @JiTHiN Log error posted

Comment: I think the issue is because i need to update camera params afte hiding toolbar?but how should i do tht?

Comment: Can you check if `surfaceChanged` is called when you hide the toolbar?

Comment: @JiTHiN yes its called

Comment: Well this causes the preview to restart and prevents the MediaRecorder from starting. And when you press the stop button it crashes since it isnt recording.

Comment: I'll write the solution below

Comment: @JiTHiN okay thanks..please write..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you capture click set a `boolean` variable

```
capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         mToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         startCapture = true;

}):
```

Hiding the `ToolBar` causes `surfaceChanged` to get called.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("error", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
 //Check if capture is set and start recording

 if(startCapture)
  {
   if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
    mMediaRecorder.start();
   }
   startCapture = false;
  }
 }
```

Comment: if i comment out entire code of `surfaceChanged` then  its working..is that better way for resolving this?

Comment: I don't think so. You need to restart the camera preview when the surface changes.

Comment: Another thing you can do is put the Toolbar over the camera preview as an overlay. Thus the surface wont change when you hide the toolbar

Comment: i can do like this also that if startcapture is true then contents inside surfaceChanged should not get called..

Comment: Glad if u can help me wid this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199834/nullpointerexception-if-try-to-record-video-again-after-cancelling